# How can I ignore an embedded struct field while inserting database?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have 2 database table;
A has 3 columns and they are X, Y, Z
B has 2 columns and they are X, W

My Go structs are like this;

```
type Base struct {
    X int
    Y int
}

type A struct {
    Base
    Z int
}

type B struct {
    Base
    W int
}
```

And I initialize my structs like this;

```
    a := A{Base: Base{X: 1, Y:2}, Z: 3}
    b := B{Base: Base{X: 1}, W: 4}
```

When I want to insert these to database using gorm.io ORM, "a" is inserted without any problem but "b" can't be inserted because postgresql gives me an error something like

```
pq: column "y" of relation "B" does not exist
```

How can I insert "b" to database without creating another base model that doesn't have "Y" field?

Answer (score 1):

When you assigning struct to another struct, and you create instance of struct, all struct fields has been filled with they default data-type value.

for example: `int` default value is 0.

So you have 2 solution for this question.

1. create two different struct(without `Base` struct), just `A` and `B`. like this: (maybe you know this solution.).

```
type A struct {
    X int
    Y int
    Z int
}

type B struct {
    X int
    W int
}
```

2. use `struct tags` to prevent from inserting with `gorm`.

**Note:** I didn`t test this.

```
type Base struct {
    X int 
    Y int `json:"y,omitempty"`
}

type A struct {
    Base
    Z int
}

type B struct {
    Base
    W int
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this doesn't solve my problem. In the question, I wanted to demonstrate a small example but in my project, I have more structs that have embedded Base struct. So your first solution doesn't solve the way I want(but this solution is better than creating another Base struct that doesn't have "Y"). And for your second solution, I tried this one before but it didn't work.

Comment: @Omeerfk I think another solution is using map[string]interface{}. then create dynamic query for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not declaring the models correctly as documentation 'Base' should have tag embedded inside both A and B then it is ok. .. . for your better understanding I am posting your code with modification.  Please be noted that I have tested in my machine it works as charm. .

here is the model declaration.

```
type Base struct {
    X int `json:"x"`
    Y int `json:"y"`
}

type A struct {
    Base `gorm:"embedded"`
    Z    int `json:"z"`
}

type B struct {
    Base `gorm:"embedded"`
    W    int `json:"w"`
}
```

here is the main function for your understanding. . .

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("vim-go")
    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres 
dbname=testd password=postgres sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic("error occured", err)
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&A{}, &B{})

    a := &A{Base: Base{X: 1, Y: 2}, Z: 3}
    b := &B{Base: Base{X: 1}, W: 3}

    if err := db.Create(a).Error; err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    if err := db.Create(b).Error; err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("everything is ok")
    defer db.Close()
 }
```

Please be sure to check the documentation of model declaration and the tags. . .
[gorm model declaration](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html)

Note: Y field will be there in B table but with zero value. . .

Answer (score 0):

```
package main
import (
"encoding/json"
"fmt"
"reflect"
)
type SearchResult struct {
OrderNumber     string      `json:"orderNumber"`
Qunatity        interface{} `json:"qty"`
Price           string      `json:"price"`
OrderType       interface{} `json:"type"`
ItemQty         string      `json:"itemQty"`
}
type Or []SearchResult
func fieldSet(fields ...string) map[string]bool {
set := make(map[string]bool, len(fields))
for _, s := range fields {
    set[s] = true
}
return set
}
func (s *SearchResult) SelectFields(fields ...string) map[string]interface{} {
    fs := fieldSet(fields...)
    rt, rv := reflect.TypeOf(*s), reflect.ValueOf(*s)
    out := make(map[string]interface{}, rt.NumField())
    for i := 0; i < rt.NumField(); i++ {
        field := rt.Field(i)
        jsonKey := field.Tag.Get("json")
        if fs[jsonKey] {
            out[jsonKey] = rv.Field(i).Interface()
    }
   }
    return out
 }
 func main() {
    result := &SearchResult{
    Date:     "to be honest you should probably use a time.Time field here, 
    just sayin",
    Industry: "rocketships",
    IdCity:   "interface{} is kinda inspecific, but this is the idcity field",
    City:     "New York Fuckin' City",
}
    b, err := json.MarshalIndent(result.SelectFields("orderNumber", "qty"), "", "  ")
   if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    var or Or
    fmt.Print(string(b))
or=append(or,*result)
or=append(or,*result)
for i := 0; i < len(or); i++ {
c, err := json.MarshalIndent(or[i].SelectFields("idCity", "city", "company"), 
 "", "  ")
 if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
 }
 fmt.Print(string(c))
 }
 }
```

The one way of doing this using omitempty fields in struct and other way is to traverse through struct fields which is expensive.
In case of performance doesn`t matter for you then you can take reference of above code snippet.